# why am i getting an Erorr here

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class shape
{
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    data(int w,int h){width=w;height=h;}
};

class Rectangle: public Shape
{
  public:
    int area ()
    {
        return (width * height);
    }
};


class Triangle: public Shape
{
public:
    int area ()
    {
        return (width * height / 2);
    }
};
int main()
{
    Rectangle rect;
    Triangle tri;
    rect.data(5,3);
    tri.data(10,2);
    cout<<rect.area()<<endl;
    cout<<tri.area()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- my code did not achive the inherting part and i am gitting erorr masseage
  that says
  "error: expected class-name before '{' token| "
- the erorr in line ( class Rectangle: public Shape )
- so what can i do to solve this?

Comment: `shape` is not the same as `Shape`.

Comment: The code shown doesn't define a class named `Shape`, so there's nothing to derive from.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058) and `using namespace std;` on top just makes a bad thing into a catastrophe, see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058). Those to together is a recipe for a lot of pain (and either one on its own is also painful - first one definitely the worst of the two).

Comment: `class Shape` -> `class Shape`. And `data(int w,int h){width=w;height=h;}` probably should be a constructor `Shape(int w,int h){width=w;height=h;}`?

Comment: @churill I believe you meant to say `class shape` -> `class Shape` (and I agree), but in your comment you used `Shape` in both cases.

Comment: thanks it solved sorry i was not soucsed

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, my bad, too late to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are several errors:**

1. The C++ is case-sensitive, `shape` isn't equivalent to `Shape` identifier. One of them must be the same as the other.
2. The class variables must be `private`, `protected` when the base class is to be derived. Otherwise, it violates the rule of OOP.
3. The datatype of `data()` defaults to `int` but nothing's returned. That's why not getting print anything. Change it to `void`.

---

Thus, the correct class code should look something like (notice comments):

```
class shape {

// The identifiers followed by 'protected:' will be visible to the class only
protected:
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    // Must be 'void' since it's returning nothing and defaults to 'int'
    void data(int w, int h) {
        width = w, height = h;
    }
};

// 'shape' != 'Shape'
class Rectangle : public shape {
public:
    int area(void) {
        return (width * height);
    }
};

// 'shape' != 'Shape'
class Triangle : public shape
{
public:
    int area(void) {
        return (width * height / 2);
    }
};
```